# How to create snippet in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, code-snippets

I'm looking for a snippet(template) that will create a procedure and also do exception handling.
I know there are already some snippets for different operations but I want to add my own snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a litte button to add the entire content of the current editor or only its selection (if any) in the snippet toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I found more detailed solution for it.

Comment: In my version of MySQL Workbench, I do not see this option, BUT Right-Clicking in a blank space in the area where the snippets are listed, gives the option to `Add Snippet from Editor Content`. Clicking that option adds the Query as a saved Snippet.

Answer (score 3):

1. Snippet is a programming term for a small region of re-usable source code, machine code, or text.
2. For MySQL Workbench all snippets are located in “C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE\snippets”. If you want add your own snippet you can add it in the above directory else you can also edit the existing one.
3. Below is the sample snippet which will create stored procedure with exception handling.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
    BEGIN
      /*
      Created By -
      Discription -
      ---------------------------
      Modified By -
      Discription -
      */
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN
      rollback;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
      @errorNo = MYSQL_ERRNO, @errorText = MESSAGE_TEXT;
      SET @spName = 'new_procedure';
      # SELECT concat('[',@spName,']-(',@errorNo,'-',@errorText,')');
      INSERT INTO errorlogs (ErrorType, `Error`, DateCreated)
      VALUES (4, concat('[',@spName,']-(',@errorNo,'-',@errorText,')'), now());
    END;
    SET autocommit = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
      #####################
      #Put your logic here      
      #####################
    COMMIT;
    END
   ```
4. Save the above file as ‘CustomeSnippet.txt’ and add it in “C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE\snippets”.
5. Now open your MySQL workbench and connect to your database. In the right side bar you will find your ‘CustomeSnippet’ listed in the dropdown.
   [image]
6. Use it and enjoy coding :-)

Comment: On my (Windows 10) MySQL Workbench 8.0 Community version 8.0.22, Snippets are located at `C:\Users\sh\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\snippets\User Snippets.txt`.  I must have saved one with a (title?) it did not like, because every time I opened the Snippets panel, Workbench crashed.  Deleting everything in that file fixed this issue, and I've been able to save and access them once again.